# Algorithm: find two positive integers whose difference is minimized and whose product is known

Tags: excel, vba, algorithm, optimization, solidworks

## Some background...

I am currently building a macro that will estimate the cost of an injection molding tool. These tools have cavities which are filled with plastic. The number of cavities a tool has is the number of parts that will be formed.

So far my program will determine the minimum number of cavities a tool can have based on customer demand. This number is always even. The tool should have an even number of cavities. Given the bounding length and width of a cavity, and setting a limit to how much space the cavities can occupy within the tool, I need my program to calculate the combination of number of cavities along the length and width whose difference is minimized and whose product is equal to the total number of minimum cavities the tool should have.

I am programming my macro is SolidWorks VBA. I first constructed this problem in Excel and used the solver tool. But, I am unable to find a way to reference the Excel Solver Tool in SolidWorks to automate this optimization problem. I am hoping to find a clever set of equations that can solve this specific problem for me. But if someone else has a better idea of what to use, that would be awesome.

## Rephrasing in an optimization format...

### Variables

- x = number of cavities along width of tool
- y = number of cavities along length of tool
- z = suggested number of total cavities

### Objective Function

Minimize x - y

### Such that

- x * y = z
- x >= 1
- y >= 1
- x <= y
- x is an integer
- y is an integer

## Example

My macro says that in order to meet demand, our tool needs to have at least 48 cavities. Find the number of cavities along the length and width of the tool such that the difference is minimized and the product is equal to 48. Ideally in this case the macro would return x = 6 and y = 8.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53014407/edit) giving us the code for your macro and telling us where exactly the problem is?

Comment: I'm afraid that this question is far too broad for Stack Overflow - please narrow your question down to a single issue so that we can help you.

Comment: The answer for x is the closest divisor of z to sqrt(z). So iterate from sqrt(z) to 1, if the number divides z, then x is that number and z / x is y

Comment: @Joe . . . 48 is pretty "no duh".  What would the result be for 42?

Comment: @juvian I've realized my mistake - I get it now :)

Comment: @GordonLinoff Probably 6 and 7 :)

Comment: @dwirony . . . I meant 44 -- would it be 4 and 11 or something more like 6 and 8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to clarify, in the question did you actually  mean to `Min y-x` rather than `Min x-y`? Otherwise there is a naïve solution taking `x = 1` and `y = z`. `Min x - y = 1-z`.

I don't program in VBA but here is the idea.

Since `x` and `y` are positive integers and there product is `z`, with `x <= y`. You can essentially start with `x = floor(sqrt(z))` and decrement until `x = 1`.

For each `x`, check if there exists an integer `y` such that `x * y = z`. If there is, break the loop and that's the pair you are looking for. Otherwise continue until `x = 1`

If you need any pseudo code so you can translate it into VBA. Here it is

```
int x, y;
for (x = floor(sqrt(z)); x >= 1; --x)
{
    y = z / x;
    if (x * y == z)
        break;
}
```

Comment: yes, I should have Min y - x. Good catch. This is a great solution. I can very easily code this in vba. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just test out a few examples.  No fancy algorithm is needed.

If you relax the condition to be 2 numbers, `x` and `y`, whose product is `z` and with a minimum difference, then the answer is `SQRT(z)`.

That is not an integer that meets your needs (in general).  However, you can then try integers around the square root to see if they divide `z`.  The first one you hit (i.e. minimum difference from `SQRT(z)`) should have the minimum difference.

If you relax the condition to be `|z - x * y|` is minimized, then I would recommend testing the numbers around `sqrt(z)`.  You need to check two cases -- the floor and ceiling of the square root (and the appropriate other number).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is needs something similar to this in the future, but can't figure out the pseudo-code I went ahead wrote it up. I wasn't sure how to output it as two values so I just threw them together as a string for the user to see.

```
Option Explicit
Function Factors(ByVal Test As Long) As String
    Dim Val As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Val = Test

    i = Int(Sqr(Val))
    While Val / i >= 2
        If Int(Val / i) * i = Val Then
            Factors = i & " & " & Val / i
            Exit Function
        End If
    i = i - 1
    Wend
End Function
```